# Which Jersey version should I use?

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I'm trying to add Jersey client to a project. I've come across two Jersey implementations. One from Sun, that should be obsolete by now, but working.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Another one from glassfish project, which however gives a missing artifact error.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m13-2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do you know which Jersey dependency I should use? (I need the client part only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.sun.jersey:jersey-client` is the one you need to use.